# how to keep the background color of the vertical axis of scroll-bar in Recycler view as transparent?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

how to keep the background color of the vertical axis of scroll-bar in Recycler view transparent when the rows in recycler view change colors depending on some value?

I have a recycler view that has rows that may have different background colors depending on some value which is set in a .java file. But by doing this the scrollbar gets a white vertical gap/slit like the image below, which looks very ugly. I kept the default color of the recycler view as transparent in the layout file. IS there any way to keep the background of the scrollbar transparent so that it doesn't look weird when scrollbar moves besides different color rows?[image]